# How to change attribute from being read-only

Tags: python

I am getting

```
Error: AttributeError : attribute is read-only (Python.Runtime.PythonException)
```

trying to override an existing method for the application running IronPython:

```
self.attribute = True
```

How to "unlock" the attribute so it could be overwritten with a new value?

Comment: Have you tried `setattr()`?

Comment: I might be read only for a reason. Is it your code that's doing it or someone elses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely `self.attribute` uses a property. This property only has a `getter` method so it's read only. To make it writable, you'd have to write a `setter` method that writes to the private value inside the class.

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property

You should consider this carefully, because most likely there is a very good reason this is a read only property. You could cause a lot of unwanted side effects because the original class designer may have never intended the value to be writable.